# exchange web services - mark message as read with soap xml

Tags: exchangewebservices

in my golang project I am using exchange web services with soap xml requests (no c# or managed API etc.) I need to mark an email message as read and for this purpose I tried the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                    xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
                    xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
                    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                        <soap:Header>
                            <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013_SP1" />
                        </soap:Header>
                        <soap:Body>
                            <m:UpdateItem
                                MessageDisposition="SaveOnly"
                                ConflictResolution="AutoResolve">
                                <m:ItemChanges>
                                    <t:ItemChange>
                                        <t:ItemId Id="AAMkA...LAAA=" ChangeKey="CQAA...nKq"/>
                                       <t:Updates>
                                          <t:SetItemField>
                                            <t:FieldURI FieldURI="message:IsRead"/>
                                            <t:Message>
                                                <t:IsRead>true</t:IsRead>
                                            </t:Message>
                                          </t:SetItemField>
                                       </t:Updates>
                                    </t:ItemChange>
                                </m:ItemChanges>
                            </m:UpdateItem>
                        </soap:Body>
                      </soap:Envelope>
```

This request does not produce any errors, although it did not mark my email message as read. I found a seaparate operation how to mark all messages as read, but in my case I need to mark as read only one message. Any ideas how to fix it would be welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Your request looks okay if you do a getitem on the same Itemid after you make the updateItem do you see the property value is changed ? Client's like Outlook and OWA generally cache so it common you may not see the change straight away.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, everything worked OK after I made a fresh GetItem request and used its updated Id and ChangeKey. Apparently they change over time so it must be taken into account.